# How do I Attach an AdaptiveCardFromJson in a LUIS Bot C#?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, adaptive-cards

I asked a similar question recently but wasn't specific enough. I see that there is some code with the AdaptiveCards NuGet Package to attach an AdaptiveCardFromJson and AdaptiveCardFromSDK, which under a the normal Microsoft Bot Model is available.

However, under the Microsoft LUIS Bot Model isn't an option, here's the code I have which returns an employee lookup result from a SQL DB Search:

```
    [LuisIntent("Who_is_Employee")]
    public async Task Who_is_EmployeeIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        EntityRecommendation recommendation;
        if (result.TryFindEntity("Communication.ContactName", out recommendation))
        {
            List<Employee> results = EmployeeService.FindEmployees(recommendation.Entity);
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                string response = "";
                foreach (Employee e in results)
                {
                    string name = e.FullName;
                    string title = e.JobTitle;
                    response += " " + name + " " + title + "\n";
                }
                await context.PostAsync(response);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync(" Sorry, I couldn't find who you were looking for.");
        }
    }
```

I would like that information to be returned as an AdaptiveCard, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the code I ended up having to use to make this successful:

```
        [LuisIntent("Who_is_Employee")]
    public async Task Who_is_EmployeeIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        EntityRecommendation recommendation;
        if (result.TryFindEntity("Communication.ContactName", out recommendation))
        {
            List<Employee> results = EmployeeService.FindEmployees(recommendation.Entity);
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                /* Single line per result */
                /*
                string response = "";
                foreach (Employee e in results)
                {
                    string name = e.FullName;
                    string title = e.JobTitle;
                    response += " " + name + " " + title + "\n";
                }
                await context.PostAsync(response);
                */

                /* Adaptive card per result */
                // Load json template
                string physicalPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../AdaptiveCards/EmployeeLookup.json");
                string jsonTemplate = "";
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(physicalPath))
                {
                    jsonTemplate = r.ReadToEnd();
                }

                var respsonse = context.MakeMessage();

                foreach (Employee e in results)
                {
                    string employeeJson = jsonTemplate;

                    employeeJson = employeeJson.Replace("{{FullName}}", e.FullName);
                    employeeJson = employeeJson.Replace("{{JobTitle}}", e.JobTitle);
                    employeeJson = employeeJson.Replace("{{Reference}}", e.Reference);
                    employeeJson = employeeJson.Replace("{{Phone}}", e.Phone);
                    employeeJson = employeeJson.Replace("{{Email}}", e.Email);
                    employeeJson = employeeJson.Replace("{{Mobile}}", e.Mobile);

                    AdaptiveCard card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(employeeJson).Card;

                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                    {
                        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                        Content = card
                    };
                    respsonse.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }

                await context.PostAsync(respsonse);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync(" Sorry, I couldn't find who you were looking for.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark,
you need to craft your adaptive card either as json or using the SDK to create an instance of AdaptiveCard. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots) is a great place to learn more about this.

Once you've crafted your card and have an instance of the AdaptiveCard class, you need to create a new message and attach the card to that message. The new message is what you'll post back to the user.

The code will look something like this

```
var card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(<your json here>);

Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
{
    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
    Content = card
};

var myRespsonse = context.MakeMessage();
myRespsonse.Attachments.Add(attachment);

await context.PostAsync(myRespsonse, CancellationToken.None);
```